# Entity Framework. Define foreign keys on an entity without extra tables and navigation properties

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Suppose I have the table **Profiles** that relates to my entity **Profile**

```
[Table("Profiles")]
public class Profile: BaseBusinessEntity {
   // Foreign key to the 'Members' table
   // one-to-one relation
   public int MemberId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }


    public DateTime? DateOfBirth{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    #region === GEO PROPERTIES ===

    public int? CountryId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int? RegionStateId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int? CityId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int? ReligionId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int? OrientationId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    #endregion

    public virtual Members.Member Member{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual City City{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual Country Country{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual RegionState RegionState{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual ProfileMap ProfileMap{
        get; 
        set; 
    }  
}
```

I have issues with the properties **'OrientationId'** and **'ReligionId'** . They should be the foreign keys to the tables 'Orientations' and 'Religions' respectively, but I don't want to create the table 'Religions' just to hold several values (Christianity, Islam, Buddhism, Hindu) or the 'Orientations' table with only three values (Straight, Homosexual, Bisexual)

I plan to avoid this by creating table **'ProfileAttributes'**and **'ProfileAttributeValues'** and have the orientations saved as the profile attribute named 'Orientation' with predefined values in the **'ProfileAttributeValues'** and have the religions saved as the profile attribute named 'Religion' with predefined values in the **'ProfileAtributeValues'** table.

```
 [Table("ProfileAttributes")]
 public class ProfileAttribute : BaseLookupEntity {

   public ProfileAttribute(){
        HasMultipleValues = false;
    }

    public bool HasMultipleValues{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public virtual IList<ProfileAttributeValue> Values{
        get; 
        set; 
    } 
}


[Table("ProfileAttributeValues")]
public class ProfileAttributeValue : BaseBusinessEntity {

    public int Id{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int ProfileAttributeId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public int TypeId{
        get; 
        set; 
    }


    public int? IntValue{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public string CharValue{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public string StringValue{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public string String100Value{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public byte[] BinaryValue{
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public ProfileAttributeValueType Type{
        get{
            return (ProfileAttributeValueType) TypeId;
        }
    }

    public virtual ProfileAttribute ProfileAttribute{
        get; 
        set; 
    }
}
```

Now I need to somehow make the **'OrientationId'** and **'ReligionId'** properties as foreign keys referencing the **'ProfileAttributeValues'** table. I mean to create a constraint that will allow only those IDs that exist in the **'ProfileAttributeValues' using Fluent API from EF** .